# List the subcategories of a given product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I've found various snippets online to list the woocommerce product categories, but I can't find a snippet that lists the subcategories and sub-sub categories for a given category.

How can I get the subcategories of a given product category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with a custom function in which you will set your "parent" product category slug:

```
function get_product_subcategories_list( $category_slug ){
    $terms_html = array();
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    // Get the product category (parent) WP_Term object
    $parent = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_slug, $taxonomy );
    // Get an array of the subcategories IDs (children IDs)
    $children_ids = get_term_children( $parent->term_id, $taxonomy );

    // Loop through each children IDs
    foreach($children_ids as $children_id){
        $term = get_term( $children_id, $taxonomy ); // WP_Term object
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); // The term link
        if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) $term_link = '';
        // Set in an array the html formated subcategory name/link
        $terms_html[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '" rel="tag" class="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
    return '<span class="subcategories-' . $category_slug . '">' . implode( ', ', $terms_html ) . '</span>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

---

**Usage example:**

```
echo get_product_subcategories_list( 'clothing' );
```

You will get an horizontal coma separated list (with links) of all subcategories for this given category

Comment: thanks for the snippet. However, now both subcategories and sub-subcategories are displaying. I would like to have it in a ul with the sub-sub categories under their parent categories? 
How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

**This is the code for get subcategory of given category:**

```
 $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' ); 

 //For checking category exit or not

 if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) : 


   foreach($categories as $category) :
      // get the children (if any) of the current cat
      $children = get_categories( array ('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'parent' => $category->term_id ));

    if ( count($children) == 0 ) {
       // if no children, then echo the category name.
        echo $category->name;
    }
  endforeach;

 endif;
```

Comment: Sorry for my small knowledge, but where do I insert the catergory slug?